# Python - Can I make a function that creates unique lists?

Tags: python, list

```
    def listmaker(n):
        if n % 4 == 0
        list ++ 'n' == []
        ....
```

I hope you can gather my intent, the function is meant to create a list, and more generally, multiple lists. The lists would need their names determined by the function so as to remain unique, and as far as I know no simple method to emulate what I attempt up there is possible (for naming or creating). Is there any way to have a function that makes lists?

Comment: How many lists do you want to make? What is the point of this? What is an example output? Right now your question makes no sense. Please add more details

Comment: Perhaps the built-in function `list` would satisfy your question =).  Otherwise, what @YagnaPatel said - please provide an example, desired output, or compiling code

Answer (score 0):

If you want many lists consider using a dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

amount = 10
nums = list(range(1,amount+1)) # 1,2,3... ,n
OrderedDict(("list{}".format(num), []) for num in nums)
```

Outputs

```
OrderedDict([('list1', []),
             ('list2', []),
             ('list3', []),
             ('list4', []),
             ('list5', []),
             ('list6', []),
             ('list7', []),
             ('list8', []),
             ('list9', []),
             ('list10', [])])
```

---

Or simply:

```
[[] for _ in range(11)]
```

outputs

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Maybe one of these can be inserted in your function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want variables to be set to empty lists then you can do the following:

```
n = 10
variable_names = ["list{}".format(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
exec('=[];'.join(variable_names) + '=[];')
```

Now, you would get the following outputs:

```
>>> list1
[]
>>> list2
[]
```